# Make a dictionary of dictionaries of list

Tags: python, dictionary

ALL,

This is what my code looks like:

```
self.dict = {
'Compressed Files': 
     {'7-zip': [ "777", "7z", "7zip", "7-zip", "lzma"]}
     {'8-zip': [ "bzip2", "tbz", "tbz2" ]}
     ^ - error here
     {'Norton': ["gho", "ghs", "v2i"]}
}
```

However python says that there is an error. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: missing some commas, and not grouping them properly also

Comment: "python says that there is an error" is not a useful question. Post the error and the traceback instead of making us guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary must have `key: value` pairs - you have one key, followed by three values.

If you want an equivalent to multiple values on a single key, then use a list:

```
self.dict = {
    'Compressed Files': [
        {'7-zip': [ "777", "7z", "7zip", "7-zip", "lzma"]},
        {'8-zip': [ "bzip2", "tbz", "tbz2" ]},
        {'Norton': ["gho", "ghs", "v2i"]}
    ]
}
```

Or if the outer dict only has one key, it might not be needed at all, just use a list.

Edit:

If you wanted to keep it a dictionary, you need two more keys, for the other files:

```
self.dict = {
    'Compressed Files': {'7-zip': [ "777", "7z", "7zip", "7-zip", "lzma"]},
    'New Key 1': {'8-zip': [ "bzip2", "tbz", "tbz2" ]},
    'New Key 2': {'Norton': ["gho", "ghs", "v2i"]}
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you also need commas between values in any collection, because the OP left some of them out.

Comment: @Lattyware, why do I need an extra list? Can't I have a dictionary of dictionaries of list?

Comment: @Igor You could, but then you need three keys - it's unclear what they would be. A dictionary is a collection of `key: value` pairs - you can't have multiple values to a single key.

Comment: OK, I guess it's different from Perl in this matter. So I will have dictionary of list of dictionaries of list. Now I do know how to access 'Compressed Files' key - it's easy. But how do I access '7-zip' key (any key) and more importantly '777' value (any value). I know I will need a nested loop, but what is exact syntax. Thank you.

Comment: @igor That is a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.dict = {
'Compressed Files': 
     {'7-zip': [ "777", "7z", "7zip", "7-zip", "lzma"]}
     {'8-zip': [ "bzip2", "tbz", "tbz2" ]}
     {'Norton': ["gho", "ghs", "v2i"]}
}
```

There is a syntax error in your code. If all three dictionaries are stored as a list under the "Compressed Files" key, you should write it as:

```
self.dict = {
    'Compressed Files': [
         {'7-zip': [ "777", "7z", "7zip", "7-zip", "lzma"]},
         {'8-zip': [ "bzip2", "tbz", "tbz2" ]},
         {'Norton': ["gho", "ghs", "v2i"]}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do I need an extra list here? I need a dictionary of dictionaries of list (sorry using Perl terminology here). So under 'Compressed Files' key I will have 3 dictionaries: 7-zip, 8-zip and Norton.